# Restrict admin menu items by django user permission

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wagtail

I'm working extending wagtail and i'm using a the next hook:
`python
@hooks.register('register_settings_menu_item')
def register_django_admin_menu_item():
    return MenuItem(_('Site Admin'), '/django-admin', classnames='icon icon-wagtail-inverse', order=20000)`

And i get a link for the django admin page, but i want to restrict that item only to user that have staff permission.
[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: Create a decorator that checks the logged in user to have staff permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    class CustomAdminMenuItem(MenuItem):
        def is_shown(self, request):
            return request.user.is_staff


    @hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
    def register_custom_admin_menu_item():
        return CustomAdminMenuItem(_('Site Admin'), reverse('admin_menu'), classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse', order=20000)
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a decorator for that:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
@hooks.register('register_settings_menu_item')
def register_django_admin_menu_item():
    return MenuItem(_('Site Admin'), '/django-admin', classnames='icon icon-wagtail-inverse', order=20000)
```

Comment: No, the item still appears in the menu.

Comment: @SalahAdDin who are you logged in as?

Comment: I created a user without staff permissions and i tested with it. In the admin appears the item but when i click on the django admin site reject me, it means, i haven't permissions.

Comment: The `staff_member_required` decorator only works on views, not `register_settings_menu_item` hook functions.